# Como obtener los datos correspondientes de un json

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Estoy enviando un array a la página "iajax_configuracion_acordeon.php", estos datos son los nombres de los acordeones, al momento de mandar los datos me los regresa vacío y lo he comprobado con un alert.

```
  let btn_guardar = $(".btn-guardar");

  btn_guardar.on("click", function(){

      let nivel = new Array();

      $(".panel-ficha .parrafo_editable").each(function(){
        nivel.push($(this));                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
      });

      $.ajax({
        url: "iajax_configuracion_acordeon.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {"nivel":JSON.stringify(nivel)},
        dataType: "text",
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        beforeSend: function(){
          btn_guardar.removeClass("label-success").addClass("label label-warning")
                    .text("Procesando...").slideDown();
        },
        success: function(rpta) {
          alert(rpta);
        }
      });

 });
```

**iajax_configuracion_acordeon**

```
    <?php
          $nivel = json_decode($_POST["nivel"]);
          echo $nivel;
    ?>
```

**Mensaje VACÍO**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pasate por este enlace [Devolver JSON en PHP y obtener datos con AJAX](https://mimentevuela.wordpress.com/2016/08/29/devolver-json-en-php-y-obtener-datos-con-ajax/).

Comment: ¿Haz revisado cuál es el valor de `JSON.stringify(nivel)`? Y de ser así ¿Cual es? Pregunto esto porque cuando se `serializa` un objeto `JSON`, no todos las propiedades del objeto que se está serializando son válidas, por ejemplo los métodos.

Comment: "Prueba 1" y "Prueba 2" son Strings y son los datos que estoy mandando.